# toggling a value in angular's scope from an external event (jquery function)

Tags: angularjs

I have a UI element on which I need to capture an event using jquery. (I cant use angular here as this a third party lib.) Then I want to access the scope of the element, and toggle a value in the scope ?

Any ideas how I can do the above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `angular.element()` to get to the scope.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/ngZ6u/

Comment: So will this work - `angular.element(#abc).scope().name = "cde"` As I am calling this from outside of angular's context. I want to change an attr in angular's scope.

Comment: Did you try it? In the jsfiddle above I added angular.element(document.getElementById('parent')).scope().name = "foo"; and that works. If you have trouble, setup a jsfiddle of your own showing what's not working so we can look at it.